# How to change Xcode generated files to Swift from Objective-C

Tags: xcode

I am new to Xcode and am not sure what I am doing. However a projected I am working on started with Objective-C, and upon realizing aspects of the language, I'd like to change to Swift. Whenever I make a view controller on storyboard, it makes it in Objective-C. How can I change the settings so it makes the auto-generated files in Swift instead?
Should be easy, right? I do not want to restart the project.

Thanks.

Comment: You may not want to recreate the project but you should consider it if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I make a view controller on storyboard, it makes it in Objective-C

A view controller on the *storyboard* has no language, and making a view controller in the storyboard does not auto-generate any files, so the question as it stands makes no sense.

What does have a language are the view controller subclass *files* you create for the project. The language of those is up to you at the moment of creation. Note the language pop-up in the File > New > File dialog:

[image]